# Анимация круговой диаграммы в MPAndroidChart

Tags: android, kotlin

Использую библиотеку MPAndroidChart для создания круговой диаграммы. https://weeklycoding.com/mpandroidchart-documentation/animations/

В документации написано, что для использования анимации нужно - 
"animateX(int durationMillis): Анимирует значения графиков по горизонтальной оси, что означает, что график будет построен в течение указанного времени слева направо."

Однако подобных вариантов не появляется.
Есть разные варианты, но именно анимации прогрузки (animateX) нет.

Уже очень долго пытаюсь найти ошибку, надеюсь поможете

[image: Вот код]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если кому-нибудь, когда нибудь понадобится круговая динамичная диаграмма на Kotlin, то держите решение:

**В xml**

```
<com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.PieChart
android:id="@+id/pieChart"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

**В коде**

```
fun createPieChart() {

val pieChart: PieChart = this.pieChart
pieChart.description.isEnabled = false

pieChart.dragDecelerationFrictionCoef = 0.99f

pieChart.isDrawHoleEnabled = true
pieChart.setHoleColor(Color.parseColor("#FCCE5C"))
pieChart.transparentCircleRadius = 60f
pieChart.centerText = "Good Job"
pieChart.setCenterTextColor(Color.parseColor("#533D2B"))
pieChart.setCenterTextSize(50f)


val pieData = mutableListOf<PieEntry>()
pieData.add(PieEntry(25f ))
pieData.add(PieEntry(75f ))


val dataSet = PieDataSet(pieData, "Hello")
dataSet.sliceSpace = 3f
dataSet.selectionShift = 5f
dataSet.colors = ColorTemplate.JOYFUL_COLORS.toMutableList()

pieChart.data = PieData(dataSet)
pieChart.data.setValueTextColor(Color.parseColor("#533D2B"))
pieChart.data.setValueTextSize(10f)



pieChart.animateXY(2000,2000)}
```

библиотека MPAndroidChart